# sqlplus takes 30 seconds to start

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus, strace

My computer is not particularly snappy, but I can load eclipse and my default workspace in less than 2 seconds.

However, sqlplus takes 30 seconds to load.

`sqlplus username/password @ exit`

Where exit.sql is simply the word "exit" runs for 30 seconds

I have run an strace and it seems to be spending all of its time on poll calls that time out.

Once sqlplus starts, it gives expected response time to sql queries.

How can figure out what this is waiting on and remediate?

edit:  New information

If I have no network connection it runs in .79 seconds

Comment: Does it help if you specify the server and database you want to connect to?  It's a long time ago and no doubt a different version, but I have a vague memory of similar behaviour caused by it attempting to connect to a non-existent 'default' server or db.

Comment: Loading shared libs?

Comment: start with /nolog to make sure it's a sqlplus problem and not a connection/name resolution problem like others are suggesting

Comment: I just discovered that if I have no network connection it runs in .79 seconds.